# Cakephp access to file (image)

Tags: php, cakephp

I have the following folder structure:

[image]

Now i want to access one of the files in this folder for this i have the following code:

```
        <?php 
    $log_directory = APP.'product_images/21/';
    ?>
    <img src=<?php echo APP."product_images/"."firefox.png"; ?>> 

</img>
```

But when i try this it says file not found.

Btw i am using `Cakephp v. 2.4`  if that matters

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Only the webroot is web-accessible

For a file to be accessible via the web it must be underneath the webroot folder. This is enforced via the [.htaccess](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/.htaccess) [files](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/app/.htaccess) in a standard CakePHP [development install](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/installation.html#development), and implicitly with a [production install](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/installation.html#production) as the webroot is the document root. If this were not the case user's would be able to browser the `tmp` `Config` etc. directories potentially accessing sensitive information.

### how to access files not in the webroot

The simplest way to achieve that is to either move the files into the webroot - or create a symlink pointing at the files:

```
$ cd app/webroot
$ ln -s ../product_images .
```

Comment: makes sence can you make an example of how you would save to a folder in webroot (create and save file to folder? )

Comment: just replace `APP` with `APP . 'webroot/'` in your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19609544/php-create-folder-if-it-does-not-exist) - though since they are images it would be more logical to put them somewhere under the `app/webroot/img` folder.