# Upload file to dynamic directoy

Tags: php, html

I have a form that uploads files to a directory.

The html and php is bellow.

The problem is line 3 of the php (I think) .It wont make the directory that it gets from teh value of the drop down. If I change it to $output_dir = "uploads"; it will create the uploads directory and put the file there.

HTML:

```
  <form id="myForm" action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<center>
  <input type="file" id="upload" name="myfile" class="custom-file-input">
</center>
<br>
<select name="folder">
            <option value="Test1">Our Photos</option>
            <option value="StockPhoto">Stock Photos</option>
            <option value="Video">Videos</option>
            <option value="Document">Documents</option>
            <option value="Other">Other</option>
        </select>
<br>
<br />
<input type="submit" value="Upload" />
<br>
<br>
<div id="progress">
  <div id="bar"></div>
  <div id="percent">0%</div >
</div>

  </form>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
//upload.php
$output_dir = $_POST['folder'];

if(isset($_FILES["myfile"]))
{
    //Filter the file types , if you want.
    if ($_FILES["myfile"]["error"] > 0)
    {
      echo "Error: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
    }
    else
    {
        //move the uploaded file to uploads folder;
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["myfile"]["tmp_name"],$output_dir. $_FILES["myfile"]["name"]);

     echo "Uploaded File :".$_FILES["myfile"]["name"] .$output_dir;
    }

}
?>
```

Comment: You need to use [`mkdir`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php) in order to "make" a directory. PHP won't create it "on the fly", as it were.

Comment: no , if line 3 is changed to uploads it makes the directory if its not there . I dont understand why it dosent do it with the drop down

Comment: Btw, this `$_FILES["file"]["error"]` should read as `$_FILES["myfile"]["error"]`

Comment: iv chnaged it in y code , it dosent make a differnce

Comment: I take it that you have folders named `Test1` - `StockPhoto` - `Video` - `Document` - `Other`? Because that's what you're telling PHP to do, to move the uploaded file to one of those folders. 
Do all those folders exist? If so, on certain systems, `Test1` and `test1`, as well as `StockPhoto` and `stockphoto` are not the same thing.

Comment: no they dont exist . Even when they do , the file dosent go to it . When line 3 was just outdir = "outputs"; it made the folder

Comment: Plus, again. I don't see code in your question that will create the folder if it doesn't exist. See my first comment.

Comment: but it did make the folder somehow

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/12700036/ and http://stackoverflow.com/a/19609708/ and http://stackoverflow.com/a/19609571/ - PHP does **not** automatically create folders. The "somehow it does" create it, sounds *too* strange. I've never in my years of using uploading features, ever come across a server that would automatically create a folder if it doesn't already exist.